# Flickering screen when using Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, ...)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, opera, intel-graphics

I had been experiencing frequent and highly bothersome screen flickering over the past few days while browsing on my laptop, particularly when playing videos or moving or resizing the browser window. This issue occurred with all Chromium-based browsers, and initially, the only workaround I could find was to disable GPU acceleration. Although effective, this solution came at a significant cost.

Yesterday, I discovered what appears to be a better solution—at least for my situation—and since it is not easy to find, I thought I would share it here to make life easier for other folks struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be related to the drivers of integrated Intel GPUs, which are present in many laptops, and their compatibility with newer versions of D3D. There may be a bug associated with D3D11, which is currently the default GPU backend. The solution is to switch the backend to the older D3D9 until the issue is resolved.

You can make this change by using chrome://flags/#use-angle or edge://flags/#use-angle and then restarting the browser.

This change immediately resolved the issue for me.

Edit: the problem is related to the combination of older Intel cards (like UHD 620) and a higher resolution (3k or 4k). For other apps, what works is to either disable gpu acceleration or (a better way) run it in a compatibility mode with Win8.

[image]